# Kendo UI - DropdownList in MVC Grid Edit/Create Popup

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've seen the other questions similar to this one, but it seems like I've done everything right so far, to no avail. 
As the title states, for one of my columns, I am trying to use a dropdownlist as the field in the popup.

Index.cshtml:

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
           columns.Bound(p => p.DEPT_ID).Width("7%").Title("Dept/ Sector").EditorTemplateName("DeptDropdown");
           ...
    }
```

Then inside of /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates
DeptDropdown.cshtml:

```
 @model MVCFinalHope.Models.Version_Utility_Model
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.DeptLookup )
    .Name("DEPT_ID")
    .DataValueField("DEPT_ID")
    .DataTextField("DEPT_ID")
    .BindTo(Model.DeptLookup)
)
```

Then inside of Version_Utility_Model.cs:

```
[UIHint("DeptDropdown")]
public List<V_TE_DEPT_LKUP> DeptLookup { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standalone custom field editors don't work in popup edit mode. You need to use a template for the whole edit form:

https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/custom-popup-editor

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates

> If the Grid is configured for pop-up editing, the Html.EditorForModel is used to get the editor HTML for the whole model.